# layout not working as it should

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Layout for 5 players:

[image] [image]

Layout for 6 players:

[image] [image]

At the 6 players layout when you click the First Player it gets weird(right image).
Anyone know what is wrong?
Thanks for any help

My activty code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView4"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="320sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_basic_4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView28">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //edit texts...

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to happen because of the keyboard that is popping up. Use

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityName"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Use nosensor if you want to use the app only for portrait modes. Use stateAlwaysHidden in the `<activity>` if you don't want android to pop that keyboard up everytime your activity opens.

Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In your activity manifest just add this

```
 <activity
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
 </activity>
```

The documentation for `adjustpan` states that

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing

Please see official doc [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: also it is possible that your scrollview is not properly set, so it is pushed when keyboard is open