# Edittext hide under keyboard when edittext create on RunTime

Tags: android

I have a layout with scroll view as root layout with one linear layout as child with vertical  orientation. I add a list of edit text dynamically in linear layout onCreate of activity. Problem is when i focus on an edit text the layout doesn't scroll up on soft keyboard up. But works perfectly if edit text are not added dynamically.
 I have already set adjust pan in manifest.

Comment: Please, share code where you add EditText dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file add the following code for this particular activity

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

or

```
Activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityName"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Use nosensor if you want to use the app only for portrait modes. Use stateAlwaysHidden in the  if you don't want android to pop that keyboard up everytime your activity opens.

Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) the official documentation and check other stackoverflow [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323472/layout-not-working-as-it-should/49324457#49324457).